# Operating system process in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, process

This one is pretty complicated. I need a C++ program(code) that takes in 2 parameters. First one marks the number of compartments in the array. Second one is size of one compartment in that array. In shared memory it is needed to create one-dimensional array and fill it with random integer values (max value is 10 000). And print values of the array, like this:

```
0. 74
1. 3
2. 66
3. 26
4. 59
...
```

*Logically, the array is being cut into pieces of equal size (size is determinated by the second argument). And it needs to create as much processes as we have pieces of the array. For example, first parameter is 3005 and second is 1000, which means there are 4 processes. Because we have 4 pieces and every is size 1000 (but the last one has only 5 elements).*

Every process takes data from it's own part of array from shared memory and prints the sum. Should look like this:

```
...
15. 16
16. 24
17. 1
Number of precesses = 5
Sum (0-4) = 228
Sum (4-8) = 237
Sum (8-12) = 322
Sum (12-16) = 228
Sum (16-17) = 25
```

---

Here is an example of the code(but not the solution) with 2 processes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int Id;
int *ZajednickaVarijabla; //shared variable

void Pisac(int i) //reader
{
   *ZajednickaVarijabla = i;
}
void Citac(void) //writer
{
   int i;
   do {
      i = *ZajednickaVarijabla;
      printf("Procitano %d\n", i);
      sleep(1);
   } while (i == 0);
   printf("Procitano je: %d\n", i);
}
void brisi(int sig)
{
   (void) shmdt((char *) ZajednickaVarijabla);
   (void) shmctl(Id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   exit(0);
}
int main(void)
{
   Id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int)*100, 0600);

   if (Id == -1)
      exit(1);

   ZajednickaVarijabla = (int *) shmat(Id, NULL, 0);
   *ZajednickaVarijabla = 0;
   sigset(SIGINT, brisi);

   if (fork() == 0) {
      Citac();
      exit(0);
   }
   if (fork() == 0) {
      sleep(5);
      Pisac(123);
      exit(0);
   }
   (void) wait(NULL);
   (void) wait(NULL);
   brisi(0);

   return 0;
}
```

--------------Here si what i have so far. This is working c++ code but without precesses, this is how print is suppose to look like. What i dont know is how to add these processes - there needs to be a certain amount of processes that share the same array(cro. polje).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
//#include<unistd.h>    
//#include<sys/wait.h>  
#include<sys/types.h>
//#include<sys/ipc.h>
//#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

//int id;
//int *brojElemenata, *velicinaPolja;

int main(){
    int brEl, velDj;
    int polje[10000], suma[10000];
    int brProcesa = 0;
    int brSuma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){ suma[i] = 0; }

    do{
        cout << "Unesite broj elelenata u polju(max 10000): " << endl;
        cin >> brEl;
    } while (brEl > 10000);
    cout << "Unesite velicinu djela polja: " << endl;
    cin >> velDj;
    cout << "" << endl;

    if ((brEl % velDj) != 0){
        brProcesa = (brEl / velDj) + 1;
    }
    else{
        brProcesa = (brEl / velDj);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < brEl; i++){
        int random = rand() % 100 + 1;
        polje[i] = random;
        cout << i+1 << ". " << polje[i] << endl;
        suma[brSuma] = suma[brSuma] + polje[i];
        if ((i+1) % velDj == 0){
            brSuma++;       
        }

    }

    cout << "BROJ PROCESA: " << brProcesa << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < brProcesa; i++){
        cout << "Suma " << i+1 << " = " << suma[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ty in advance and sry for my programing language, I'm not even native :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you give us more details: the code you have so far, what have you tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: I can give you the code but you won't understand it cuz the variables and most of everything is in croatian.

Comment: The code is not necessarily for be, but for people over here that are able to help you. We only need the relevant parts of your code that can describe the problems you run into.

Comment: The problem has three parts: 1) create N processes, 2) for a given process, determine which elements of the array it should combine, 3) coordinate the reports of all of the elements, so that they appear in the correct order. Which of these parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: (Also, if you can write code with English keywords, surely we can read code with Croatian variable names!)

Comment: I'm having problem with creating N processes.